# How much time does AWS step function keeps the execution running?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I am new to AWS Step Function. I have created a basic step function with Activity Worker in the back end. For how much time, does the Step Function keeps the execution alive and not time out if the execution is still not picked by the activity worker?

Comment: I think you are asking for SWF Simple workflow not for Step Function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For how much time, does the Step Function keeps the execution alive
>   and not time out if the execution is still not picked by the activity
>   worker?

1 year

You can specify `TimeoutSeconds` in activity task which is also a [recommended way](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/sfn-stuck-execution.html)

> ```
> "ActivityState": {
>   "Type": "Task",
>   "Resource": "arn:aws:states:us-east-1:123456789012:activity:HelloWorld",
>   "TimeoutSeconds": 300,
>   "HeartbeatSeconds": 60,
>   "Next": "NextState"
> }
> ```

Step functions can keep the task in the queue for maximum 1 year. You can find more info on Step Functions limitations on [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/limits.html).